# Jquery datepicker display for multiple forms

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, erb, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have my code structured in such a way that clicking on an 'Edit' button displays a hidden form (written in embedded ruby) within a 'div' html tag and within that form is a text_field_tag whose id is used to tie to a datepicker using Jquery.

Using my current view code and jquery datepicker code in rails : I can click on an edit button and select a date using the text_field_tag for each form. However, when I try to submit that datepicker value it only gets submitted for the first form (for the first 'td element).

Im guessing im doing something wrong with the Jquery code.Can anyone guide me as to how I can submit the datepicker value for the corresponding form (the closest form within 'td' on button click) as opposed to only submitting for the first form(first 'td' element)

Heres my code:

**VIEW in RAILS:**

```
    <h2>Files</h2>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Download Link</th>
     </tr>
     <% @files.each do |file| %>
     <% filename = file.split('/').last %>
    <% object = @bucket.objects[file] %>

    <tr>         
    <td><%= filename %></td>  

    <td>

    <div class="file_description"><%= object.metadata['description']%>    

    <button id ="button1" type="button"  class= "btn btn-default   
      edit_description"   onclick="Window(this)">Edit</button> 

    </div>
     <div id = 'hidden_form' class="file_description_update" >
      <%= form_tag({:action => 'update_file_info'}, multipart: true) do %> 
        Update File Description: <%= text_area_tag :description %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :s3_path, file %>  
        <%= hidden_field_tag :prefix, @prefix %>
       <%= text_field_tag 'user_input' %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %> </td> <br />
      <% end %>
    </div>

    </td>
```

**Code for Jquery in application.js file in Rails**:

```
     //= require jquery
     //= require jquery_ujs
     //= require twitter/bootstrap
     //= require bootstrap
     //= require_tree .

     //= require jquery.ui.all
     //= require jquery.ui.datepicker



     $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $( "button.edit_description" ).on( "click", function( event ) { 
     $(this).closest('td').find("div.file_description_update" ).show();
     $(this).closest('td').find("div.file_description_update" 
     ).find('#user_input').datepicker(); 

      });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got it to work by NOT assigning any id to the text_field_tag and only using a class for accessing the text_field_tag in each form for each file in the loop using jquery --so essentially in my solution only jquery provides unique ids for the form. I read it in another forum somewhere.

My solution in code:

**RAILS VIEW**:

```
      <%= text_field_tag '', '',:class => "datepicker" %>
```

**RAILS application.js file**: (JQUERY code for datepicker):

```
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('.datepicker').each(function(){
      $(this).datetimepicker();
      });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got done working on a similar problem. part of the issue is that jquery modifies the id and gives a class to all attributes that invoke it. One solution is to use knockout to abstract away the need to manually modify the DOM. A good solution can be found here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NAgNV/)

There's a whole mess of questions relatiing to the datepicker causing problems when people try to mod the DOM directly and get some unexpected results.

Her's my solution I posted in another question:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var $el = $(element);

                //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                var options = { minDate: 0};
                $el.datepicker(options);

                //handle the field changing
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
                });

            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                    $el = $(element),
                    current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

                if (value - current !== 0) {
                    $el.datepicker("setDate", value);   
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To be honest, Im a newbie about coding in jquery and dont understand much of the code so if possible, can you guide me with which parts of the code you posted or the code from jfiddle would I need for my application? Id really appreciate.

Comment: So as far as i can tell, you have a loop that is creating a form and you have this line: $(this).closest('td').find("div.file_description_update" 
     ).find('#user_input').datepicker();

Comment: You actually have a problem where the id tag isn't unique, its always "#user_input", that needs to be unique so there is a 1-1 relation between the forms and the datepickers. It might be helpful to make a function that returns a unique id or use a class. I don't know if knockout plays nice with the rails view render

Comment: @roquequery Thanks for the reply. And that function would have to be in Jquery or Ruby you think? Please let me know

Comment: It would be a rails function but you might want to abstract that away as jquery modifies classes and Ids for datepicker

Comment: Im sorry, by Rails you mean the function would be ruby? what would do mean by I would want to 'abstract that way'?  Thanks